# how to update .edmx file without effecting all the other model classes?

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

how to update `.edmx` file without effecting all the other model classes?

when I update the `edmx` file  it recreates all the other classes and this is a problem for me because I made some changes on the other classes so how can I modify it without affecting the other classes.

For example this is one of my classes

```
public partial class company
{
    public company()
    {
        this.Departments = new HashSet<department>();
        this.CustomersOfTheCompany = new HashSet<company_customers>();
        this.CompaniesTheCompanyCustomerFor = new HashSet<company_customers>();
        this.CustomerProjectDetails = new HashSet<cus_pro_connector>();
        this.CompanyAsSupplier = new HashSet<company_suppliers>();
        this.CompanyAsCustomer = new HashSet<company_suppliers>();
        this.Tickets = new HashSet<oneTimeAuthenticationTicket>();
    }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Company name is required")]
    [StringLength(200, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Length Of The Company Name Should  Be More Than Three Letters")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Country { get; set; }

    public int company_id { get; set; }
    public string Logo { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    private CompanyDTO _CDTO = new CompanyDTO();
    public CompanyDTO CDTO { get { return this._CDTO; } set { this._CDTO = value; } }

    public virtual ICollection<department> Departments { get; set; }
    public virtual country CountryOfTheCompany { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<company_customers> CustomersOfTheCompany { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<company_customers> CompaniesTheCompanyCustomerFor { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<cus_pro_connector> CustomerProjectDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<company_suppliers> CompanyAsSupplier { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<company_suppliers> CompanyAsCustomer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<oneTimeAuthenticationTicket> Tickets { get; set; }
}
```

so when I modify the .edmx the class attributes will no longer be available.

Comment: It is better to use a Partial Class to make changes

Comment: @DawoodAwan I edited my example so how can I save the class attributes from the modifications

Comment: another part of the answer is that you have to create another partial class in a separate file if you wanna add additional properties or methods to the model class to make sure that they are safe of remove when you update the `edmx` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to retain edits to generated files when you re-generate them. If you need to apply attributes to generated code, there is a [MetadataType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) mechanism that allows you to specify validation attributes in another partial class.

See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174519/how-can-i-use-attributes-on-a-property-defined-in-the-other-half-of-a-partial-cl) or [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) for further information on this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your example - But I will explain here:

Let's say you have the following Entity Models:

[image]

And the `User.cs` looks like this:

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.UserWindows = new HashSet<UserWindow>();
    }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserWindow> UserWindows { get; set; }
}
```

Add a new file and call it `Extensions.cs`, then create a New Partial Class in this File:

[image]

Then you can Add Properties to this Class:

```
public partial class User
{
    public int NewUserId { get; set; }
}
```

And whenever you create a New User Object you will see your new Properties:

[image]

Similarly you can do this for `UserWindow.cs`

```
Extensions.cs:

public partial class User
{
    public int NewUserId { get; set; }
}

// Similarly you can do

public partial class UserWindow
{
    public string MyNewProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then

[image]