# ef5 database first data annotation

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, data-annotations, ef-database-first

I am starting MVC4 with VS2012.  I am also using EF5 with the "Database First" method of creating my classes.

However because the generated glasses can be regenerated I cannot put the Data Annotation details to assist with validation.

I have seen some code snippets that use MetaData and partial classes but I was wondering if anyone knows of a small compilable example that I can look at and pull apart to better understand how the vasious classes interlink.

Many many thanks for any help.
Dave

Comment: What kind of validation you would like to perform and what kind of validation mechanism (custom validation attribute, IValidatableObject etc) are you thinking about? I think you have a few options (buddy classes, partial classes, updating T4 templates) depending on what you want to validate and how you want to validate it.

Comment: Hi Pawel. Sorry for not replying sooner but I did not get a email notification. Basically the type of validation I want to use is the standard  [Required] etc data annotation validation so that the View can automatically use it.  Many thanks for replying. Dave

Comment: I think you need to look at buddy classes. Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141(v=VS.100).aspx, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999936/using-dataannotations-with-entity-framework and http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx (search for "buddy")

Comment: Many many thanks for that Pawel.
From the quick look (and trying to update the project to VS2012) it looks just what I need.  I'll experiment some more later.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve what you need through extending models. Suppose that EF generated the following entity class for you:

```
namespace YourSolution
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class News
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }                  
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        public virtual UserProfile User{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

and you want do some work arounds to preserve your you data annotations and attributes. So, follow these steps:

First, add two classes some where (wherever you want, but it's better to be in `Models`) like the following:

```
namespace YourSolution
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(NewsAttribs))]
    public partial class News
    {
         // leave it empty.
    }

    public class NewsAttribs
    {            
        // Your attribs will come here.
    }
}
```

then add what properties and attributes you want to the second class - `NewsAttribs` here. :

```
public class NewsAttrib
{
    [Display(Name = "News title")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the news title.")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    // and other properties you want...
}
```

**Notes:**

1) The namespace of the generated entity class and your classes **must be the same** - here `YourSolution`.

2) your first class **must** be `partial` and its name **must** be the same as EF generated class.

Go through this and your attribs never been lost again ...

Comment: I was going to submit an edit but I can't since the edit wouldn't be at least 6 characters long.  Anyway, in the last code example the class name should be NewsAttribs not NewsAttrib.