# Is a View Model the only way to annotate your model if you're using the EF model generated classes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

If you're not coding up POCO's and you're forced to use the model generated by Entity Framework or one of the extensions, is there any way to annotate the model other than:

1) Using a view model

and

2) Annotating the model generated by EF, which should of course be ruled out as it will anyway be over-written every time the model is updated or refreshed from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if I understand your question, but seems you need write DataAnnotatios to Model autogenerated by EF and the DataAnnotations can't be lost when you update the EF. If it is you need see: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999936/using-dataannotations-with-entity-framework).